# Delete data when self-referencing table

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I've run into a problem trying to clean up data from a MySQL table. The problem is that we need to use the table in the subquery to identify what needs to be deleted.

```
DELETE 
FROM dates
WHERE event_ref IN (*list of event_refs*)
AND person_ref IN (
  SELECT person.person_ref
  FROM person
  JOIN dates ON dates.person_ref = person.person_ref AND dates.event_ref = 14
  WHERE dates.date < CURDATE()
)
```

The `Subquery` gives all people with a date earlier than today. The list of event refs is a list of events that we want to delete, and which *excludes* `event_ref = 14`

Treating the query as a SELECT returns everything we want to delete, but MySQL complains when try to use the delete.

I don't really want to go to the length of creating a view to reference into the above query as the clean up is a one time event

Comment: *"but MySQL complains when try to use the delete."* What does it do? Does it moan? Or does it maybe show you an error message, you could have shown us, too, to let us see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's shorten the query. You can get rid of the `person` table here; there is nothing you do with it.

```
DELETE 
FROM dates
WHERE event_ref IN (*list of event_refs*)
AND person_ref IN
(
  SELECT person_ref
  FROM dates 
  WHERE event_ref = 14 AND date < CURDATE()
);
```

Now MySQL doesn't like to directly access a table it is deleting from. In MySQL you'll have to wrap the table hence in a pseudo subquery:

```
DELETE 
FROM dates
WHERE event_ref IN (*list of event_refs*)
AND person_ref IN
(
  SELECT person_ref
  FROM (SELECT * FROM dates) d
  WHERE event_ref = 14 AND date < CURDATE()
);
```

Comment: Good spot. The person table is left over from some other cleaning up that we are doing - but in this instance can go. Will check the rest Monday AM

Answer (score 0):

You could use subquery:

```
DELETE 
FROM dates
WHERE event_ref IN (*list of event_refs*)
AND person_ref IN (SELECT person_ref FROM (
  SELECT person.person_ref
  FROM person
  JOIN dates ON dates.person_ref = person.person_ref AND dates.event_ref = 14
  WHERE dates.date < CURDATE()) sub
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join  on a subquery for the same table

```
    DELETE dates FROM dates
    INNER JOIN (
          SELECT person.person_ref
      FROM person
      JOIN dates ON dates.person_ref = person.person_ref AND dates.event_ref = 14
      WHERE dates.date < CURDATE()) sub
    ) t on t.person_ref = dates. person_ref
    AND  event_ref IN (*list of event_refs*)
```